# Android: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, singleton

I was reading through StackOverflow about this question and I still haven't found a solution. I notice that sometimes, my app throws this error:

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:962)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:599)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
        ...
```

I have a file called `DatabaseHelper.java` using this approach to get an instance of it:

```
public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

Then I have methods like this one (that it crashed in the line `cursor.moveToFirst()` with that error). It almost never crashes, but sometimes it does.

```
public Profile getProfile(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROFILES + " WHERE " + KEY_PROFILES_ID + " = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    Profile profile = new Profile();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        doWhatEver();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return profile;
}
```

So that's it, in all the methods I use:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); (or Writable)
```

And then I close the cursor and the db. In this case, the error got throw in the line:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

I do not see why the error says the db is closed if I am calling `this.getReadableDatabase()` before. Please support! Thank you :)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Remove

```
db.close();
```

If you try another operation after closing the database, it will give you that exception.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteClosable.html#close()) says:

> Releases a reference to the object, **closing the object...**

Also, check out
[Android SQLite closed exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002022/android-sq-lite-closed-exception/25379071#25379071) about a comment from an Android Framework engineer which states that it is not necessary to close the database connection, however this is only when it is managed in a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: I used the synchronized word in the getInstance() as it shows in this blog: http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection and then I deleted all the db.close(). It seems that is working fine. I was also reading here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608498/best-place-to-close-database-connection that is not really necessary to close it. Anyway the documentation is not clear.

Comment: I had an unnecessary db.close() in my DbProvider class. And it was only giving error in Samsung Galaxy 3.

Comment: Removing db.close() fixed this for me.

Comment: When should I actually perform db.close(); when I have multiple SQL operations? @ammarcse .

Comment: @Sp4Rx, call it when your done with your db set of operations overall for the current call.

Comment: I'm doing multiple sql operations in multiple threads at the same time, so I don't know exactly which will be the last operation. Presently I'm not using db.close() but I guess it's not right by keeping it open after all the operations. Is there any way to close after all thread finishes ? @AmmarCSE .

Comment: Assuming the `db` object is shared between threads. And, assuming you cannot capture an event when the operations are done or you are not using any utilities such as observables. The only way I can think is to manually keep track by having an int represent the number of threads and then each time one one is done, decrement, and then check whether to close or not.

Comment: Although the statement about closing DB connection is not necessary, that is only if you are managing in a ContentProvider which is not clear in the answer.

Answer (score 29):

I currently have the same problem. While removing the `db.close()` solves the issue for me, I think the issue is caused by multi-threading. Here is my research.

`SQLiteOpenHelper` holds a reference to `SQLiteDatabase`, when `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` called, it will return the reference, if the `SQLiteDatabase` is **closed** or null, a new `SQLiteDatabase` object will be created. Note that inside the get method, codes are guarded in a synchronized block.

`SQLiteDatabase` is a subclass of `SQLiteClosable`. `SQLiteClosable` implements a reference counting scheme.

- When first created, the count is 1.
- When the database operation methods run (like insert, query), it will increase the count, and decrease the count when methods end. But the cursor operations are NOT protected by reference counting.
- If the count decreases to 0, connection pool will be closed and a member `SQLiteConnectionPool` object will be set to null, and now the `SQLiteDatabase` is **closed**;
- `SQLiteDatabase.close()` will decrease the count by 1;

So, if you have a single-threaded scheme, closing the `SQLiteDatabase` will be fine because `SQLiteOpenHelper` will just re-recreate it.

If you do multi-threading, then you will run into trouble. Say thread A and thread B both call `getReadableDatabase()`, and `SQLiteOpenHelper` returns the SQLiteDatabase it holds, and then thread A first finished its operation and call `SQLiteDatabase.close()`, now the `SQLiteDatabase` object thread B has is **closed** so any subsequent db operation calls or cursor method calls will throw the exception.

Comment: Ok so what is the solution for 2nd option? ( multi-threading)

Comment: I think my crash is also due to mutithreading. I'm doing several `db.close()` in a service, but there is a websocket handler thread which in an incoming message also  calls `getWritableDatabase()`, tries to delete an item from the DB, and then also calls `db.close()`. Before the websocket handler reaches the `db.delete()` the service has most likely called `db.close()` in its `db` variable, which caused the websockets thread to operate on a closed database connection.

Comment: @HardikJoshi Solution for 2nd option is to synchronize the code where cursor is being accessed.

Comment: @Prudhvi Thanks, this works! I wasn't sure which methods may cause problems in my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class, so I made all methods in that class `synchronized` just to be safe. Could this cause any issues? Should I be more cautious with using the `synchronized` keyword?

Comment: @VratislavJindra I would say you just need to synchronize the code only when it is necessary. Without the need, say if two threads are allowed to concurrently read from a certain shared resource, synchronization would just make your code execute slowly since other threads will be waiting when one is accessing that particular shared resource.

Comment: i am gettig the same error but my app is working just fine , no crash no abnormal behavior nothing , so should i bother to remove that error

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple error in Android architecture initialisation of room database with getApplicationContext(), this means that your application has one instance of the database reference, no matter how many activities create an instance of it, therefore if you close it in any activity the others will throw that exception.

Essentially don't just check the activity throwing the exception but every activity for db.close()

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem, have not been able to fix it. I have found a possible clue:
I have a sync thread that is running all the time:

```
    Item ii = dbHelper.popPendingUpload();
    if (ii != null)
            upload(ii);
```

And inside DBHelper

```
public Item popPendingUpload() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db
            .rawQuery("SELECT * FROM items WHERE state = 0 LIMIT 1",
                    new String[] {});
    boolean hasNext = res.moveToFirst();
    Item ii = null;
    if (hasNext) {
        ii = //load item
    }
    db.close();
    return ii;
}
```

The error also shows up in the moveToFirst() method call. As the thread is poping items out in an infinite loop, the first time it works ok, the second time the error appears. The interesting part is that if I put a breakpoint and step through the code, the error does not show any more. I am testing on a real device using Android 4.1.

I know, is not an answer, but it may help. I'll keep on testing.

Comment: By the way, I am using this isolated open-read-close DB calls pattern all over my code. It works every where else

Answer (score 3):

```
//close database after cursor is closed like:

if(cursor.getCount() != 0){

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
      //do operation
    }
}

cursor.close();
database.close();
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you close the database before access to database from your app.

You have to edit getProfile() to

```
public Profile getProfile(long id) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

  try {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROFILES + " WHERE " + KEY_PROFILES_ID + " = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    Profile profile = new Profile();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      doWhatEver();
    }
    cursor.close();
  finally {
    db.close();
  }
  return profile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have  a  error  like  yours  ,here   my  code:

```
  try {
                        String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD;
                        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
                        //空双引号为原表没有的字段
                        String temp = "";
                        int existIconPath = cursor.getColumnIndex("iconPath");
                        int existAudioID = cursor.getColumnIndex("audioID");

                        if (existIconPath == -1 && existAudioID == -1){
                            temp = "url, downed,total,path,name, audioTitle, audioFileID,\"\",\"\"";
                        }else if (existIconPath == -1 && existAudioID != -1){//iconPath不存在
                            temp = "url, downed,total,path,name, audioTitle, audioFileID,\"\",audioID";
                        }else if (existIconPath != -1 && existAudioID == -1){//audioID不存在
                            temp = "url, downed,total,path,name, audioTitle, audioFileID,iconPath,\"\"";
                        }else {
                            return;
                        }

                        db.beginTransaction();
                        String tempTableName = "_temp_"+DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD;
                        String sqlCreateTemp = " ALTER TABLE "+DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD+" RENAME TO "+tempTableName+";";
                        db.execSQL(sqlCreateTemp);

                        final String TB_TESTPAPERINFO_CREATE = "Create  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                                + DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD
                                + "(url TEXT, downed TEXT,total TEXT,path TEXT,name TEXT, audioTitle TEXT, audioFileID TEXT,iconPath TEXT, audioID TEXT);";
                        db.execSQL(TB_TESTPAPERINFO_CREATE);

                        String sqlBackupData = "INSERT INTO "+DB_TABLEDOWNLOAD+" SELECT "+temp+" FROM "+tempTableName+";";
                        db.execSQL(sqlBackupData);
                        String sqlDrop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '"+tempTableName+"';";
                        db.execSQL(sqlDrop);
                        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                        db.endTransaction();
                    }
```

I  use  return  before  db.beginTransaction(),my  code  return  before beginTransaction,but  I  endTransaction in  finally . if  you do not beginTransaction  and    endTransaction ,the exception  will appear.

so check  your code  about  the db.beginTransaction and  endTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention one more possibility to get this error in case someone searching this post run into the same case:

**Using Database Inspector in Android Studio may cause this error in some situation.**

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error message and solved it by removing a db.close() in another activity.

I had a background process for population of a virtual table in one activity and then a db.close() in another activity.

The db.close() didn't do any harm before my long background process ran.