# Android.database.sqllite.SQLiteDatabaseLocked Exception:database is locked (code 5): ,while compiling:PRAGMA journal_mode

Tags: android, javafx, gluon

I use **SQLite** for a Gluon Mobile App in my Android. When I access the database for the first time it works without problem, but the another time I have a Exception:

> "Android.database.sqllite.SQLiteDatabaseLocked Exception:database is
>   locked (code 5)

The code to access the database is:

```
if (Platform.isAndroid()) {
  Class.forName("org.sqldroid.SQLDroidDriver");

  try {
    dir = Services.get(StorageService.class)
               .map(s -> s.getPrivateStorage().get())
               .orElseThrow(() -> new IOException("Error: PrivateStorage not available"));
    File db = new File(dir, DB_NAME);
    DBUtils.copyDatabase("/databases/", dir.getAbsolutePath(),   
DB_NAME);
    dbUrl = dbUrl + db.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(dbUrl);
    c = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
  } catch (IOException ex) {

    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, ex.getClass().getName());
    alert.setContentText(ex.getMessage());
    alert.showAndWait();
  }

  c.setAutoCommit(false);
  System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

  stmt = c.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM COMPANYn;");

  while (rs.next()) {
    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String name1 = rs.getString("name");
    // System.out.println(name1);

    items.addAll(name1);

    ET.getItems().addAll(items);

    ET.getSelectionModel().select(0);

  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  c.close();
```

Somebody can help me please. Thank for help.

Comment: You don't show the code where you close the sql statement, the results or the connection. Do you close them?

Comment: @JoséPereda I update the Code above. Yes i close it. Or it is wrong?

Comment: Why don't you follow the GluonSQLite sample? Use try-catch-finally properly.

Comment: Thank to Answers me @JoséPereda .I try it but i have the same Error

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this same error in the same situation (connecting to sqlite, using Gluon and running on Android). Worked fine on the desktop, but got the same error as in your title for Android.

Interestingly, I found that my 2nd SELECT statement rather than my 1st was the one throwing the error. The 2nd statement was in a separate method, after closing the statement, resultset, and connection from the 1st one.

I eventually found that ***not* closing my sqlite connections** seemed to resolve this issue for me. This seemed odd since I'm used to closing them at the end of a transaction, method, etc, but it seems this is not abnormal in sqlite.

See here for some related info on the topic:

[Android: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293572/android-cannot-perform-this-operation-because-the-connection-pool-has-been-clos)